# Prefix all the routes in Lumen

Tags: php, routes, lumen

Is there a way in Lumen to prefix all of my routes?

The thing is that I'm versioning my API via URI and for every group that I create I have to set the prefix to 'v1/*' like:

```
$app->group(['prefix' => 'v1/students/', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Students\Data'], function () use ($app) {
    $app->get('/', 'StudentController@get');
    $app->get('/{id}', 'StudentController@getByID');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, route groups in Lumen do not inherit any settings, which was intentional to keep the router simpler and faster ([see comment here](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/85#issuecomment-99933038)).

Your best bet will probably be to create a route group per version, in order to define a base prefix and controller namespace for that version. But, your individual routes inside those route groups will need to be slightly more verbose. Example shown below:

```
// creates v1/students, v1/students/{id}
$app->group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function () use ($app) {
    $app->get('students', 'Students\Data\StudentController@get');
    $app->get('students/{id}', 'StudentController@getByID');
});

// creates v2/students, v2/students/{id}, v2/teachers, v2/teachers/{id}
$app->group(['prefix' => 'v2', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function () use ($app) {
    $app->get('students', 'Students\Data\StudentController@get');
    $app->get('students/{id}', 'Students\Data\StudentController@getByID');

    $app->get('teachers', 'Teachers\Data\TeacherController@get');
    $app->get('teachers/{id}', 'Teachers\Data\TeacherController@getByID');
});
```

Comment: The nested group prefix overwrites the parent prefix, tested.

Comment: @CarlosFdev I apologize. You are absolutely correct. I have updated my answer with another suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could prefix all routes in your **/bootstrap/app.php**.
Currently, there should be something like

```
# may be slighlty different, since I typed this from memory
$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    require __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php';
});
```

As you can see, this loads the web.php file and makes the $router variable available.
You can rewrite this to load any php file in the routes directory and prefix all those routes via

```
$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    // load all files in routes directory, prefix all of them
    $globalPrefix =  "/v1";
    $router->group(["prefix" => $globalPrefix], function($router) {
        $routes = glob(__DIR__ . '/../routes/*.php');

        foreach ($routes as $route) require $route;
    });
});
```

As you can see, all required routes are wrapped in $router->group with your application wide route prefix.