# Laravel - lumen : Unable to resolve route handler localhost - MAC os

Tags: laravel, lumen, php-8

I was following a tutorial to getting started with lumen project for APIs,

Routes/web.php

```
// Working
Route::get('/', function () use ($router) {
 return $router->app->version();
});

// Error - Unable to resolve route handler
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
 Route::get('template', [TemplateController::class, 'index']);
});
```

[Out put of http://localhost:8000/api/template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mycE.png)

Versions - PHP 8.0, Lumen 9.0, XAMPP 8.0.25,
OS - MAC

Run the project `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/` command

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prefix all the routes in Lumen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454204/prefix-all-the-routes-in-lumen)